# Scaling of Error Bars in Paired Measurements with an Unknown Signal

Tags: statistical-significance, measurement-error, error-propagation

I'm grappling with a statistics problem related to the scaling of error bars, and I'm hoping to gain a clearer understanding.

Scenario:

I'm attempting to measure the spectrum of a sample. For the sake of simplicity, let's say I measure 10 wavelength bins, aiming to detect a specific 'bump' in my spectrum, which corresponds to the emission of a particular atomic line. Each of these 10 data points has an associated error bar derived from photon counting (Poisson statistics).

However, superimposed on the spectrum I'm trying to measure is an unknown signal. To counteract this unknown signal, I take another measurement either right before or after the original one, but of a different sample where the spectrum should ideally be flat. I'm operating under the assumption that this unknown signal remains consistent for both measurements since they're taken in close temporal proximity. My strategy is to subtract this secondary spectrum (which would be flat if not for the unknown signal) from the primary target spectrum. Naturally, this means the measurement errors from the reference spectrum will carry over to the target spectrum.

From my understanding, I can adjust for this by increasing the errors of the target spectrum. The 'new' error bar sizes in my target spectrum would then be calculated as:

$$\sigma = \sqrt{error^2_{reference} - error^2_{target}}$$

Question:

If the above is accurate, I'm trying to understand the scaling of the error bars if I were to conduct multiple such paired measurements. Suppose each of these paired measurements is taken daily, and the unknown signal varies significantly. However, we can still assume that this signal remains consistent for each paired measurement taken in close succession. Given this, the intrinsic spectrum of the target sample remains unchanged, but the interfering unknown signal varies with each measurement.

Considering the fluctuating nature of this unknown signal, am I introducing any unaccounted noise when calculating $\sigma = \sqrt{error^2_{reference} - error^2_{target}}$? How would the errors scale if I stack multiple measurements? And would they compare to the case where I would have no unknown signal and could just stack the measurements assuming each individual measurement would have $error_{target}$?

I hope this makes sense. If you need any additional information, please let me know.

All the best, and thanks in advance!